# Pandas throws "index must be monotonic" when filling NAs during reindexing, but indices already are

Tags: python, pandas

I was reindexing a `pd.Series` using another dataframe I already had, when pandas threw `ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing` at me. Both the series and the dataframe indices *are* monotonic, in fact:

```
>>>groups.index.is_monotonic
True
>>>data.index.is_monotonic
True
```

Additionally, this works:

```
groups.reindex(data.index,).fillna(method="bfill")
```

but this doesn't:

```
groups.reindex(data.index, method="bfill")
```

What gives?

Pandas version is 1.3.5

Comment: can you share a reproducible example?

Comment: I'll see if i can come up with one